# The Javadoc of VimPortType of vSphere SDK

Tags: java, web-services, sdk, vmware, vsphere

I'm currently learning the vSphere web service SDK, in their API reference, I have only found the methods and properties of all the managed objects and data objects. But I can't find the javadoc of the class VimPortType, which is the entrance of the entire web service.

I've searched on the web site of VMware, but no luck.

Does anybody know where I can find the Javadoc of this class please, Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not something that is available; I've also scoured the internet to no avail. I'm not sure why this isn't provided when it's how to interface with the VI API.

I've yet to see if this is an option for our team, but I have heard a lot of great things about the vijava library for interfacing with the VI API instead. http://www.doublecloud.net/prod_vijavang.php